# Pip uninstall is not working

Tags: python, django, pip

After I run `pip uninstall FeignCMS` I get this error...

```
Cannot uninstall requirement FeignCMS, not installed
Storing debug log for failure in /var/folders/t5/7n05d5fn1qq3n4mjz9gt1ykw0000gn/T/tmp5w4vX5
```

But when I run `pip freeze` I can see it in the list...

```
FeinCMS==1.11.0
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `FeignCMS` != `FeinCMS`

Comment: lol *slaps forehead* - that worked by the way